# Improve speed of GCP SQL Failover

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I've been trying out GCPs SQL high availability options. Is there a way to improve the fail over speed?

Attempting manual failovers through the UI takes literally over 5 minutes where mysql is completely unavailable.

I am using the smallest second generation 5.7 instances possible currently with no traffic hitting it.

It looks like it's actually stopping and starting instances. I'm having trouble seeing how this is an option for "HA" meaning minimal downtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you are at the mercy of the managed service provider there. GCPs managed database offering isn't that great, they lag quite far behind the others, they want to steer you onto BigTable, BigQuery and Cloud Spanner. If you are committed to GCP and have a hard requirement for HA then your best option is probably Spanner. – [Gaius](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/63/gaius)

Comment: This is incorrect - moving to Spanner only for HA is probably the incorrect move. Spanner's biggest benefit over traditional SQL servers are scale and global constancy. BigTable, BigQuery, and Cloud Spanner all have different pros and cons, and you should use the best tool for the job at hand.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything you can do to improve the failover time, but you can add a [read replica](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/create-replica) to have read access to your data while your instance is recovering.

If you aren't locked down to MySQL, you should also try the Postgres version of Cloud SQL - it uses a faster method for recovery and from my personal experience is generally down for ~30-60 seconds. Each version has it's own page on HA, which talks about how they work: [MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability), [Postgres](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/high-availability)